# sqlalchemy: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following 3 classes:

```
class Resource:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = Column(Text)
    data = Column(Binary)
    type = Column(Text)

    def set_resource(self, path, data, type):
        self.path = path
        self.data = data
        self.type = type

class EnvironmentResource(Base, Resource):
    __tablename__ = 'environment_resources'
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('environments.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    def __init__(self, path, data, type):
        self.set_resource(path, data, type)

class Environment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'environments'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    identifier = Column(Text, unique=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    description = Column(Text)

    _resources = relationship("EnvironmentResource",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        passive_deletes=True)
    _tools = relationship("Tool",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        passive_deletes=True)

    def __init__(self, name, identifier, description):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.description = description

    def get_resource(self, path):
        return self._resources.filter(EnvironmentResource.path==path).first()
```

On calling get_resource, I am told that 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'filter' - I've gone through the documentation and can't quite figure this out. What am I missing, so that I may be able to filter the resources corresponding to an environment inside my 'get_resource' method?

PS: I know get_resource will throw an exception, that's what I'd like it to do.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In order to work with the [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) as with `Query`, you need to configure it with `lazy='dynamic'`. See more on this in [Dynamic Relationship Loaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders):

```
_resources = relationship("EnvironmentResource",
    cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    lazy='dynamic',
    passive_deletes=True)
```

Comment: could someone please explain to a database n00bie what lazy='dynamic' means and does?

Comment: Similarly, if you have the same problem with a `backref`, you need to replace `backref='items'` in `relationship` with something like `backref=db.backref('items', lazy='dynamic')`.

Comment: without lazy='dynamic', you get directly the result on env.environment_resource. But with lazy='dynamic', it returns a <sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery> - you can do str(env.environment_resource) and it will give you the SQL query on to which you can tack on filter etc