# sqlalchemy multiple nested queries with filters from one table AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one table,

```
class Sale(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    vente_no = db.Column(db.String(50))
    lampshade = db.Column(db.String(30))
    brocante = db.Column(db.String(30))
    buyer = db.Column(db.String(255))
    pays = db.Column(db.String(255))
    QT = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prix_de_vente = db.Column(db.Float)
    poste = db.Column(db.Float)
    total = db.Column(db.Float)
    bordeaux = db.Column(db.Integer)
    amazon = db.Column(db.String(255))
    bordeaux_euros = db.Column(db.Float)
    bordeaux_comm = db.Column(db.Float)
    amazon_euros = db.Column(db.Float)
    amazon_comm = db.Column(db.Float)
    PID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("period.id"))
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    description = db.Column(String(255))

    P_id = db.relationship("Period")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

I need to create one query with two parameters and filters so that I can
iterate through the rows. I am following this tutorial [nested queries](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm)  which I am 
following, here is my subquery

```
poste_eu = db.session.query(
    (Sale.id, Sale.poste, Sale.pays).filter(or_(Sale.pays=='United Kingdom', Sale.pays=='France', Sale.pays=='Germany',\
           Sale.pays=='The Netherlands', Sale.pays=='Italy', Sale.pays=='Slovakia', Sale.pays=='Ireland',\
           Sale.pays=='Malta', Sale.pays=='Belgium', Sale.pays=='Spain')).label('poste_eu')
    ).group_by(Sale.id.asc()).subquery()
```

But in terminal this gives the following error

> ```
> >>> poste_monde = db.session.query(
>   ...     (Sale.id, Sale.poste, Sale.pays).filter(~or_(Sale.pays=='United Kingdom', 
>      Sale.pays=='France', Sale.pays=='Germany',\
>   ...            Sale.pays=='The Netherlands', Sale.pays=='Italy', Sale.pays=='Slovakia', 
>      Sale.pays=='Ireland',\
>   ...            Sale.pays=='Malta', Sale.pays=='Belgium', 
>     Sale.pays=='Spain')).label('poste_monde')
>   ...     ).group_by(Sale.id.asc()).subquery()
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
>   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filter' ""
> ```

this same query written like this works

```
def poste_monde(pid, month):
    p_monde = Sale.query.with_entities(Sale.id, Sale.poste).filter(Sale.PID==pid, extract('month', Sale.date)==month,\
          ~or_(Sale.pays=='United Kingdom', Sale.pays=='France', Sale.pays=='Germany', Sale.pays=='The Netherlands',\
           Sale.pays=='Italy', Sale.pays=='Slovakia', Sale.pays=='Ireland', Sale.pays=='Malta', Sale.pays=='Belgium',\
           Sale.pays=='Spain', Sale.pays=='FR', Sale.pays=='GB')).all()
    return p_monde
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578070/sqlalchemy-instrumentedlist-object-has-no-attribute-filter) question and wonder if I should have my classes set
up in a similar way with lazy relationships.

my query will have nine subqueries like the example shown, the Paremeters
are 'pid' and 'month' and the filters are a list of countries

I need help to get the first query working so that I can add the rest!!!?
warm regards
Paul

Comment: I don't see how this is different than `(1, 2, 3).filter(True)` which yields the same error. What makes you think that `(Sale.id, Sale.poste, Sale.pays).filter(...` is valid?

Comment: hi @Nae, Thank you for taking a look, (1,2,3).filter(True) is how I laid out the query "def poste_monde(pid, month):" query, so (1,2,3) are "with_entities" which I guess from your comment is my first mistake!