# SQLAlchemy One-to-(Some of Many) relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, model-associations

I currently have a SQLAlchemy model `User` which has two types of measurements associated with it, weight and height. These are added as foreign keys.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    weight = db.relationship("Weight", cascade="all,delete")
    height = db.relationship("Height", cascade="all,delete")

class Weight(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "weight"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    weight = db.Column(db.Float)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))

class Height(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "height"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    height = db.Column(db.Float)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

I want to be able to add more types of measurements, without having to rebuild the database structure every time. Therefore I thought about using a generic `Measurement` model which has a column for the type of measurement (not an `Enum` so I can add new types easily):

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    measurements = db.relationship("Measurement", cascade="all,delete")

    @property
    def weight(self):
        pass    # <-- No idea what to do here

    @property
    def height(self):
        pass    # <-- No idea what to do here

class Measurement(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "measurement"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    value = db.Column(db.Float)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    measurement_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('measurement_type.id'))
    measurement_type = db.relationship("MeasurementType")

class MeasurementType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "measurement_type"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    unit = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
```

With this new model, how do I get only the e.g. weights? With the current models, this is as simple as this, where `current_user` is the currently logged in user:

```
current_user.weight
```

But I guess it would have to be something like this:

```
current_user.measurements.filter(Measurement.measurement_type == "Weight")
```

(Which doesn't work, as `current_user.measurements` returns a list.)

Similarly, how do I then add a new value to the measurements? Currently I do this:

```
current_user.weight.append(Weight(date=date, weight=weight))
db.session.commit()
```

Do I basically need to replicate the low-level implementation of `relationship` in order to filter by two things, the user ID and the measurement type?

Or can I somehow achieve this using an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)? Or (correctly) using the `primaryjoin` argument of `relationship`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to achieve this is to use dynamic lazy loading on the relationship, as also recommended on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579347/4042267) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11578070/4042267). This way the return type is no longer a simple list, but an SQL object. This also uses a simple string as the measurement type, instead of a lookup table.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    measurements = db.relationship("Measurement", cascade="all,delete", lazy="dynamic")


class Measurement(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "measurement"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    m_type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    value = db.Column(db.Float)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

Afterwards you can use normal filter methods on the measurements:

```
list(current_user.measurements.filter_by(m_type="weight"))
```

And adding a new row is also very simple:

```
current_user.measurements.append(Measurement(m_type="weight", date=date, value=weight))
```